# Customized bulleted list items in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am just a beginner in ASP.NET. My question is simple, I wanna add list items dynamically from the code behind file and I want each item to have a text and couple of images as hyperlinks. The HTML sample should be like,

```
<ul>
  <li>do foo &nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="some_image.png" /></a></li>
  <li>do bar &nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="some_image.png" /></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The number of items is dependent on the collection retrieved by the code behind file.

P.S. my code behind file is written in C#

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control is the simplest way to create a customized bulleted list, plus it gives you complete control over the HTML you generate. To use it, set up a template like this:

```
<ul>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ListRepeater">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <li>do foo &nbsp;<a href='#'><img src='<%# Eval("ImageSource") %>' /></a></li>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Then in your code-behind (or declaratively in your markup, depending on your preference), set the repeater's data source and bind it:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Some method you've defined to get your images
  List<string> imageList  = GetImages();
  ListRepeater.DataSource = imageList;
  ListRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

ASP.NET renders the template once for each item in your data source.

The `Repeater` control has more features than what I've shown here, but this should get you started. Good luck!

---

**Edit**: a year after writing this answer, I still think repeaters are the best option among server controls, but more and more I prefer `foreach` statements right in my .aspx templates:

```
<ul>
    <% foreach(Image image in this.Images) { %>
        <li>do foo &nbsp;<a href='#'><img src='<%= image.Source %>' /></a></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: i think it should be written as,   

<ul>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ListRepeater">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <li>do foo  <a href='#'><img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(...) %>' /></a></li>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>

Anyways, thanks a lot for the guidance

Comment: Glad to help! It's true that using "DataBinder.Eval(...)" is clearer, but I can't quite bring myself to insist on it (or even use it!).

Answer (score 6):

Just use the Repeater control. Simply and easy.  :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it simple or easy, but I think it's the best way in standard webforms (+1).  Enjoy the ItemDataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net BulletedList. [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?query=BulletedList&ac=3)